# Output the maximum duplicated lines in bash

Tags: bash

I have an output of the following format in bash, from a script I wrote that returns the number of duplicate file names and the file name itself within a particular directory.

```
 19 prob561493
 19 prob564972
 19 prob561564
 11 prob561965
  8 prob562172
  7 prob564449
  6 prob564155
  6 prob562925
  6 prob562739
```

Using `output | head -n1`, I can get the first entry of the above output to get `19 prob561493`. However, I also want to print out other problems that share the same number of max duplicates, so in this case, the final output should look this way:

```
  19 prob561493
  19 prob564972
  19 prob561564
```

I tried to do a `cut -d" " | uniq -c` to first get the integer of the output and then only show the unique results, but that returned ALL the duplicate results.

How can I print only the duplicated maximum duplication lines?

Comment: Is input assumed to be sorted, as your sample data shows?

Comment: Yep, you can assume it was sorted in a descending order with the max on top. My scripts that come before has this solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked how to do this in bash.  I have to say that awk may provide the clearest method to achieve what you want:

```
awk 'NR==1{n=$1} $1==n{print;next} {exit}'
```

This gets the count from the first field, then prints each line with that first field, and exits when the field doesn't match.  It assumes sorted input.

But the task can still be handled in bash (or even just shell) alone, without spawning extra commands or subshells.

```
#!/bin/sh

n=0
while read count data; do
  printf "%3d %s\n" "$count" "$data"
  if [ $n -gt 1 -a "$count" != "$lastcount" ]; then
    break
  fi
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

There are zillions of ways you can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is sorted numerically on the first column you can use `awk` for this in the following way

```
awk 'NR==1 {max=$1} {if($1==max){print $0}}'
```

this grabs the first field of the first line and stores that in variable `max` and only the lines that match this number are printed subsequently

Comment: Could you edit this so the max integer is automatically used instead of manually writing it?

Answer (score 0):

You may first retrieve the number of max occurence, and then grep on that file:

```
NB=$(head -n1 error.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
egrep ^$NB error.dat
```

Here `egrep` means that `grep` should interpret the pattern as a regex; and `^` represents the beginning of a line

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if ($1>max) max=$1; next} $1==max' file file
19 prob561493
19 prob564972
19 prob561564
```

In the 1st pass we are getting max value from `$1` stored in variable `max` and in 2nd pass we just print all the records that have first field same as `max`.

Comment: For very large files, this will perform badly because you're scanning the file twice.  Note that the input is already sorted. Please see my answer below, or check Pankrates' answer; he had the same (superior) awk solution.

Comment: Works for me.  What indication do you have that the sample input provided by the OP does not reflect his actual data?

Comment: By reading OP's comment below Pankrates's question and nowhere OP wrote that input file is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to extract the '19' and grep+regex to get the lines that start with `19\b`. Assuming your file-name is "output":

```
grep -E "$(head -n1 output | awk '{print $1}')\b" output
```

Comment: This isn't portable.  The `\b` shortcut only works in certain versions of grep. You should either use the true classes, or qualify your answer to reflect the version your solution is restricted to.

Comment: @ghoti `\b` is word boundary in regex (not a "shortcut"). I had no idea it was not supported by some versions of grep (worked fine for me on Centos, Ubontu and Mac). Do you mind to provide more information in regards ?